# Docusign - How to return signers status

Tags: docusignapi

We have a developer account and I am starting to integrate it into our system. The system is based on Laravel/VueJS and I've 2 additions Eric Tucker Docusign SDK and the official Docusign SDK.

How do I get the status of where a signer/recipient is at? On the docusign portal it will show "Need to sign" but then below, it shows "Viewed dd/mm/dd hh:mm" <- Where do I get this from?

Cheers
Carl.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Envelopes:get call for the current envelope status.

Or better, have DocuSign update your app when the envelope status changes. See [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4)

The `delivered` datetime is when a signer recipient first viewed the envelope.